# "Can't resolve 'fs'" on Next.js using google-cloud/kms

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-kms

The titled error happened in my environment.
I want to know how to resolve this error.

Surely I installed 'fs'.
My program is below. Just a simple, but an error has happened.

```
import {KeyManagementServiceClient} from '@google-cloud/kms';
const client = new KeyManagementServiceClient();
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

And then, an error message is here.

```
./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/gcp-residency.js:19:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/build/src/v1/ekm_service_client.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/build/src/v1/index.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/build/src/index.js
./src/pages/gcp.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Versions

```
    "@google-cloud/kms": "^3.3.0",
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5
```

Please help me, someone.

Answer (score 2):

As 'fs' is built-in module of Node.js, so probably that may help you:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found#the-module-youre-trying-to-import-uses-nodejs-specific-modules

In Next.js we can not import node specific modules inside separate component, only on pages level.

Comment: Thank you for your tips.
I edited like URL link. But the error hasn't been resolved.